# Using strsep in kernel space to separate a string

Tags: c, string, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm trying to separate a string based on some delimeter in a kernel module.

I'm trying to use the [`strsep()`](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/teaching/lectures/systems/08_09/docs/kernelAPI/r2690.html) function, but when I try to use it my kernel crashes.

Can someone identify the bug in the code below?

```
char *test = "test1:test2:test3";
char *token = test;
char *end = test;
while (token != NULL) {
    strsep(&end, ":");
    token = end;
}
kfree(test);
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing a string literal and `strsep()` modifies it, it's undefined behavior, try like this

```
char test[] = "A:B:C:D";
```

you should not `free(test)`, not the one in this suggestion, and also not the one in your code.

You are `free()`ing `test`, which is worst, you should learn about pointers and dynamic memory before attempting to write c code, specially if it will be a kernel module.

If you want, the compiler may warn you about that, but you should help the compiler by declaring any pointer that will point to a string literal, as `const`, for example in your case

```
const char *test = "Whatever";
```

then the compiler will say something like *the first parameter to `strsep()` discards `const` qualifier*, which would probably not prevent it from compiling but will let you see that you did something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for you rcomment and explanation. WIll accept.